# Route traffic from host to docker container permanently

Tags: networking, network-manager, docker

I need to route the traffic destinated to 10.0.0.0/16 to a container (172.17.0.2).

I'm able to do it once everything is running using  `ip route add 10.0.0.0/16 via 172.17.0.2` and everyting is working as expected.

However, how can I make it persistent to reboot?

I tried using nmcli but it seems docker recreate a docker0 connection with another uuid wich doesn't keep the settings

```
$ nmcli con show docker0 | grep 'ipv4.routes\|uuid\|interface-name'
connection.uuid:                        b7dc86cd-2025-4288-bf3b-2535f2d0ee3c
connection.interface-name:              docker0
ipv4.routes:                            { ip = 10.0.0.0/16, nh = 172.17.0.2 }
connection.uuid:                        d0ea574b-3849-4eea-80e2-07406f68ae0e
connection.interface-name:              docker0
ipv4.routes:                            --
```

(PS: I can't use netplan)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could add that line

> `ip route add 10.0.0.0/16 via 172.17.0.2`

to your `.bashrc` file? It will be executed every time you log in.

Comment: Unfortunatly it's a server, so I want the route to come even if I don't login after a reboot. I tried to put the command as a cron job with a 60 second delay after a reboot, (to wait for docker), but it didn't work.

Comment: @ElioMaisonneuve maybe you can try adding these lines to the netplan config file (located in `/etc/netplan`):

```
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        eth1:
            [... your config ...]
            routes:
                - to: 10.0.0.0/16
                  via: 172.17.0.2
```
replace `eth1` with your server's interface and then `sudo netplan apply`. The change should be persistent.